# How to deal with two different questions with one same answer

Tags: discussion, exact-duplicates

I just found a [question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/182785/how-does-exhaust-affect-certain-abilities) which is different from [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/155043/league-of-legends-damage-modifiers-while-channeling/155060#155060) that I've answered a while ago. Yet the answer of the older one is valid for both questions.

How exactly should we handle these? I mean the questions are somewhat different, they are not exactly "duplicates" but the answers of those two are basically identical or at least similar. Would it be okay to edit one of both questions to make things more clear?

The user of the question said that he didn't know about the dupe, which i  can fully understand since the older question really sounds a bit more specific while the newer one faces the broader (more clear) problem.

What exactly can we do to prevent duplicate answers?

Comment: http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/7359/3062

Comment: this question was marked as a duplicate. oh the irony...

Answer (score 1):

I can't say anything about your specific situation, because I lack knowledge about League of Legends for that.

I don't see anything wrong with a duplicate answer if the questions are different, if two different questions both result in the same answer, that's fine. For a stupid example: The questions "1+1=?" and "How many hands do people normally have?". Both have the answer "2", but they are not dupes.

Your example sounds a bit like someone asked a question about a specific problem, and now a more generalized question is asked, but it still has the same answer. I'd say: close as dupe. A dupe closure is not a bad thing.